# How to generalize mapply to work "crosswisely"?

Tags: r, function, vectorization, apply, mapply

Mapply applies a 2-dimensional function to the 1st elements of each m-dimensional vector, and then to the 2nd elements of each, etc. The result is an m-dimensional vector.

For example

```
> mapply(sum, 1:5, 12:16)
[1] 13 15 17 19 21
```

Now, is there a DIRECT alternative to mapply that applies the function "crosswisely" to each of the first vector's and each of the second vector's components?

The result would be a m^2-matrix.

Comment: Did you mean `outer(1:5, 12:16, '+')`  or `Vectorize(function(x) x+1:5)(12:16)`

Comment: How would outer work for f(x,y)=x^2+x^y-3 or any other two dimensional function?

Comment: Try `f1 <- function(x,y) x^2+x^y-3;  outer(1:5, 12:16, f1)`

Comment: Indeed! Thank you. Are you willing to write an answer or how do we close this, otherwise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try `outer`

```
f1 <- function(x,y) x^2+x^y-3
outer(1:5, 12:16, f1)
```

which would be similar to

```
t(Vectorize(function(x) f1(x,12:16))(1:5))
```